# Cannot get react-admin to work inside <Provider/> tag (Including React-Admin In Another Redux Application)

Tags: react-admin

I want to use react-admin inside my react application and be able to use it like any other react component:

```
<Provider....
    <Admin.../>
    ...other components...
</Provider>
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial but cannot get it working:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html

Did anybody get this working?  I would love to see a repo of just a vanilla react-admin working inside a  tag.  I've followed the examples here but getting so many errors it's not usable.

Comment: What's not working exactly? What errors are you seeing? It's impossible to help you with so little code

Answer (score 0):

Let try provide data into Admin tag

`const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
<Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
         ...other components...
</Admin>`
Reference : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html